# Нужно ограничить ввод цифр

Tags: jquery, html

Здравствуйте, нужно что бы пользователь когда вводил цифры, jquery проверял например вводит он 354, а максимальное число только 350! как это можно сделать? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант скрипта уже привёл [@mountpoint](/users/13008/mountpoint), а я отмечу, что для последних версий браузеров, кроме Firefox, достаточно использовать [это](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/max):

```
<input type="number" max="350" min="0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

что-то такое придумалось http://jsfiddle.net/LR8p8/1/